# Deploying to an Ultrabook with an SSD using MDT 2013 Update 2

Tags: deployment, ssd, wds, imaging, mdt

I am having issues Deploying a custom image of Windows 10 to an Ultrabook with an SSD using MDT 2013 Update 2.

I have had numerous conversations with Lenovo Support but not getting any solid answers from them.

The laptop we want to copy the image to is a Lenovo Yoga 900. This device has no NIC.

I've changed the BIOS settings to legacy so I can boot with a USB.

I have injected the driver for a USB Ethernet Adapter into my WinPE Image and made a bootable USB from that.

Once booting with the USB, I can connect to our Deployment Server no problems and can select the task sequence I want. When I try to run it fails because it can only see the USB as the only storage.

I confirmed this by pressing F8 to bring up CMD and going into DiskPart and listing the disks, only the USB is showing. I also then confirmed this when in the BIOS, it only sees the SSD with UEFI enabled.

Has anyone come across this and maybe might be able to shed some light on how I can easiest way to mount our custom image to this SSD?

Thanks in advance.
JB.

Comment: Is the USB both storage and ethernet? Are you booting the WIM file from the usb device and then using another usb for connectivity?

MDT has the ability to do a complete offline install without needing to network boot. http://serverfault.com/questions/725388/can-i-run-windows-deployment-services-from-start-to-finish-without-using-the-net/725905#725905. If that answered your question then I will rewrite it as an answer.

Comment: I was booting with a USB ethernet card and a separate USB with the WinPE image on. I can only seem to boot on a USB with Legacy enabled in the BIOS, but this, in turn, does not detect the internal SSD. The only way to see the internal SSD is to enable UEFI but then cannot find a way of loading my own custom image on it!? I hope this makes sense? Thanks for your assistance Elliot Labs :)

Comment: Check out this answer, it contains instructions on how to set up a UEFI BCD. http://serverfault.com/a/829903/216286

Comment: Oh, I am glad that you find a solution. Awesomeness!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this.

This link helped me.
https://superuser.com/questions/873312/booting-from-usb-with-uefi-bios-to-install-windows-8-1

Downloaded Rufus and loaded my WinPE image with the USB formatted with UEFI FAT32 (Default)